# How to create a conditional statement with multiple values in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have four columns in excel that will either hold the value "Yes", "No" or "NAP"  I need to write a formula in a 5th column that will display "Yes" if at least 1 out of 4 of the values = "Yes" and the other 3 = "NAP".  The 5th column would also = "Yes" if it were two Yes's and two NAP's or three Yes's and 1 NAP, etc.

If all four columns = NAP than the 5th column needs to display "NAP".

If any of the four columns = "No" than the 5th column has to = "No".

Here is what I have so far...

=IF(AND(BS3="Yes",BT3="Yes",BU3="Yes", BV3="Yes"),"Yes",IF(AND(BS3="NAP",BT3="NAP",BU3="NAP", BV3="NAP"),"NAP","No"))

The only problem with this formula is that it is too absolute, it will not allow for the 5th column to display "Yes" if there is a combination of NAP and Yes in the four columns.

I hope I was clear enough and that you can help!

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
=IF(OR(A1="NO",B1="NO",C1="NO",D1="NO"),"NO",IF(OR(A1="YES",B1="YES",C1="YES",D1="YES"),"YES","NAP"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I find nothing wrong with Tripp's answer, you can also do it with the `COUNTIF` function which might be easier to read

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1:E1,"No")>0,"No",IF(COUNTIF(B1:E1,"NAP")=4,"NAP",IF(COUNTIF(B1:E1,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")))
```

of course just change the cell references to match where you need them

Comment: Chancea, thank you for this.  There is one issue that maybe you could help with.  Everything works except for the fact that when my four columns are blank the 5th column shows a value of "yes".  I need it to show a value of "No".  Can you possibly help with that problem? - Thanks.

Comment: @user3687650 no problem sorry I hadn't checked this earlier, I edited my answer and added an additional check which should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the confusion.  I ended up with this which seems to work just fine.  =IF(COUNTIF(T3:V3,"NAP")=3,"NAP",IF(SUM(COUNTIF(T3:V3,{"Yes","NAP"}))=3,"Yes","No"))

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"No"),"No",IF(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Yes"),"Yes","NAP"))
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly, so close I can taste it!  The issues I need to get around from the results of your formula are that the "5th column" needs to start with the value of "No" and all four columns need to have values of "yes" for the 5th column to show a value of "yes".   Thank you so much for your help...

Comment: 'all four columns need to have values of "yes" for the 5th column to show a value of "yes"" - that sounds different than your original request that " display "Yes" if at least 1 out of 4 of the values = "Yes"". If you're still looking for an answer, please clarify. As to the starting state, are you saying that if a column is blank the result should be "No"?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  I eventually got it, I ended up doing this...   =IF(COUNTIF(T3:V3,"NAP")=3,"NAP",IF(SUM(COUNTIF(T3:V3,{"Yes","NAP"}))=3,"Yes","No"))